# Switch images with a data template

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I know that already some questions exist but I can not fix my problem with them.

**Problem:** I try to change a image with a data template but just the default image is visible.

**Code:** 
My xaml code is like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MultiTemplate">
        <Image Height="17" Width="17">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage VideoControllerTester;component/Resources/Start.svg}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MultiTrigger}" Value="start">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage VideoControllerTester;component/Resources/Start.svg}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MultiTrigger}" Value="stop">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage VideoControllerTester;component/Resources/Stop.svg}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

 <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource MultiTemplate}"/>
```

In the code behind I set MultiTrigger = "start" or "stop".

**Question:** Can I show the images with the content control? Or I do some dumb stuff with the data template?

Edit:

```
    public string MultiTrigger
    {
        get { return _multiTrigger; }
        set
        {
            _multiTrigger = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The DataContext of the ContentControl should be set to an object with a MultiTrigger property. The MultiTrigger property setter should fire a PropertyChanged event.

Comment: ...alternatively, if `MultiTrigger` is a property of your window class, you must bind it using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}`.

Comment: Besides that, you don't actually need a ContentControl with a DataTemplate. You could as well make the Image Style a resource and directly apply it to an Image control.

Comment: @Clemens Can you show me a example for it?

Comment: That's difficult because you haven't shown the declaration of your view model and MultiTrigger property.

Comment: I hope my edit helps, but I just want an simple example, cause I don't know where I stuck..

Comment: It's still not clear where (in which class) the MultiTrigger is declared.

Comment: Oh sry for that..MultiTrigger is declared in the class "MainViewModel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is a `MainViewModel` class with a `MultiTrigger` property (which btw. is a strange property name), you would assign an instance of the view model class to the MainWindow's `DataContext`, either in code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Or in XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Then you would declare the Image Style as a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="ImageStyle">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage VideoControllerTester;component/Resources/Start.svg}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MultiTrigger}" Value="stop">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage VideoControllerTester;component/Resources/Stop.svg}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

and apply it to an Image control:

```
<Image Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
```

Then change the property value somewhere in the MainWindow's code behind by directly accessing the view model instance like this:

```
((MainViewModel)DataContext).MultiTrigger = "stop";
```